# Output and Input at Same Line using IOSTREAM

Tags: c++, io, iostream

I want to use the *iostream* input and output operators in the same statement, not to be nicer to the user but the look I was trying not successfully obtained.

Code fragment:

```
int value = 0;
std::cout << "Number 1: " << std::cin >> value << std::endl;
```

Is there any way to do this using only cin cout?

Comment: using cout and cin keeps the code readable; a bunch of << >> >> << >> << would make it a mess.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
struct IO {
    template <typename T>
    const IO & operator << (const T & t) const {
        std :: cout << t;
        return *this;
    }

    template <typename T>
    const IO & operator >> (T & t) const {
        std :: cin >> t;
        return *this;
    }
};

IO () << "Number 1: " >> value;
```

Comment: Sorry, but here it's not working. I don't know if is my problem on implement.

Comment: @Bruno: "not working" is the second least useful thing you could possibly say here, behind only "BANANAS!"

Comment: It wanted to be const-qualified because `IO()<<foo` yields a const reference to a temporary. Fixed now.

Comment: @spraff: Yet you were returning non-const `IO&`. I don't disagree, but I think it's a bit more complex than you assert.

Comment: It doesn't like the final `std::endl`. What's the type of `std::endl` anyway?

Comment: It works as it is without the endl. http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/manipulators/endl/ I agree this solution needs some refinement but this is basically the right idea.

Answer (score 2):

a bit messy but I think this is what you wanted

```
std::cout<<"Data : "<<val<<std::endl<<(std::cin>>val)<<"\r"<<"\t\r\n"<<std::flush;
```

Answer (score -3):

```
std::cout << "Number 1: ";
std::cin >> value;
```

Should do the trick.

Comment: that way I know, but I wish the other half as it launched a challenge for me and others.

Comment: The OP specifically asked for an _alternative_. Plz2readTheQ!

Comment: That's a silly constraint, since it makes the code less readable, but replace the first `;` with `,`, and join the lines, and the constraint is met.

Comment: Note that the "accepted" answer used something like 15 lines.  Even more than I did.

Comment: James, those extra lines can go into a header/library and be *reused*. Or do you want to delete all those extra lines in the `std` namespace and stick with printf?

Comment: @James The accepted answer answered his question, you didn't. And spraff is right, the single line with an IO struct can be reused, so in a document with say 200 cout/cin lines, it saves more space than yours. Not that line count *really* matters.

Comment: @spraff It doesn't matter where they go, they are still extra lines.  They were conceived uniquely to solve this one, artificial problem, and probably would never be used in production code anyway.  But that's not really the issue: if you say &ldquo;one line&rdquo;, then it really should be just one line.